# Vbscript Function Print Output

Tags: vbscript, wmic, windows-scripting

I have create VBscript to enumerate user in group

```
Function GetUserInGroup() 
strComputer = "localhost"
Set colGroups = GetObject("WinNT://" & strComputer & "")
colGroups.Filter = Array("group")
For Each objGroup In colGroups
    For Each objUser in objGroup.Members
        If objUser.name = "yayantritaryana" Then
            WScript.stdout.write objGroup.Name + " "
        End If
    Next
Next
End Function
WScript.stdout.write "Group=" + GetUserInGroup
```

But when i execute it, the output is'nt what i expected

[image: Script Output]

The output I Wanted is like

```
Group=Administrator SQLAdmin Sysadmin
```

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x7hbf8fa%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) has a purpose (eg. delivering a string of space separated group names). For that you assign the desired result to the function's name (other languages use some kind of return statement):

```
Function GetUserInGroup()
    GetUserInGroup = "pi pa po"
End Function

WScript.stdout.write "Group=" & GetUserInGroup()
```

output:

```
cscript 29053176.vbs
Group=pi pa po
```

A function shouldn't have [side-effects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_%28computer_science%29) (like your

```
WScript.stdout.write objGroup.Name + " "
```

which prints names to the console `before` you output "Group=" in the last line of your script). Instead concatenate the objGroup.Names.

The operator for string concatenation is [&](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sx97884w%28v=vs.84%29.aspx).

The (possibly empty) argument list of a function call must be enclosed by (); these param list () are illegal for [Sub](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt223ahx%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) calls.

Some extra code as food for thought:

```
Function GetUserInGroup()
    For Each s In Split("pi pa po")
        GetUserInGroup = GetUserInGroup   & s & "*"
'       GetUserInGroup = GetUserInGroup() & s & "*"
    Next
End Function

WScript.stdout.write "Group=" & GetUserInGroup()
```